# Как спарсить текст внутри тега без самого тега bs4, python

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup, bs4

Как спарсить "Имя заголовка"

```html
<div class="tn-atom" field="tn_text_1645189052805" style="line-height: 30px;">Имя заголовка</div>
```

Я пока совсем новичок в python, пробовал по-разному:

```
person = soup.find("div", attrs={"style": "line-height"}).get_text()
person = soup.find("div", class_="tn-atom").get_text()
```

но результат один (`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'`)

Comment: Может быть сайт динамический и у вас в soup может не быть этого div. Первый вариант - "style": "line-height: 30px;"

Comment: Лучше использовать для поиска class или этот пользовательский аттрибут field, который, по-видимому, хранит уникальный код блока

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А вы html код передали в объект класса `BeautifulSoup`?

если у вас не установлен модуль lxml, то в консоли нужно выполнить: `pip install lxml` или можно в коде заменить `'lxml'` на стандартный парсер Питона - `'html.parser'`, но он медленее.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html = '<div class="tn-atom" field="tn_text_1645189052805" style="line-height: 30px;">Имя заголовка</div>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml') # Или soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
person = soup.find("div", class_="tn-atom").get_text()
print(person)
```

Вывод:

```
Имя заголовка
```

Comment: with open('doctors_urls.txt', "r", encoding="utf8") as file: lines = [line.strip() for line in file.readlines()] for line in lines: q = requests.get(line) result = q.content soup = BeautifulSoup(result, "lxml") person = soup.find("div", class_="tn-atom").get_text() print(person) 
lxml установлен. – 
Darkus
 прямо сейчас

Comment: Запустил ваш код. Всё должно работать, если в супе есть тот html, который вы указали в вопросе. Вы сделайте ```print(soup)```, есть ли там нужный вам html?